# Dynamic Pivot in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, dynamic, pivot

I am trying to do a dynamic pivot on the last two columns that i take from one table and am joining onto the contents of another table.  I need the Name values to pivot to the header fields and the Value values to fill in correspondingly underneath. This is my current query:

```
USE Innovate
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column 
SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') 
       + QUOTENAME(NAME)

FROM (SELECT DISTINCT NAME FROM Innovate.dbo.Table1 WHERE Name IS NOT NULL) AS ATTRIBUTE_NAME
WHERE Name LIKE 'Suture_-_2nd_Needle_Code'
OR Name LIKE 'Suture_-_Absorbable'
OR Name LIKE 'Suture_-_Antibacterial'
OR Name LIKE 'Suture_-_Armed'
OR Name LIKE 'Suture_-_Barbed'
OR Name LIKE 'Suture_-_Brand_Name'
OR Name LIKE 'Suture_-_C/R_2nd_Needle_Code'
OR Name LIKE 'Suture_-_C/R_Brand_Name'
OR Name LIKE 'Suture_-_C/R_length'
OR Name LIKE 'Suture_-_C/R_Needle_Code'
OR Name LIKE 'Suture_-_Coating'
OR Name LIKE 'Suture_-_Dyed'
OR Name LIKE 'Suture_-_Filament'
OR Name LIKE 'Suture_-_length_inches'
OR Name LIKE 'Suture_-_Looped'
OR Name LIKE 'Suture_-_Material'
OR Name LIKE 'Suture_-_Needle_Code'
OR Name LIKE 'Suture_-_Needle_Shape'
OR Name LIKE 'Suture_-_Needle_Style'
OR Name LIKE 'Suture_-_Noun'
OR Name LIKE 'Suture_-_pleget'
OR Name LIKE 'Suture_-_Popoff'
OR Name LIKE 'Suture_-_Suture_count'
OR Name LIKE 'Suture_-_Suture_size'

--Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic 

SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
  N'SELECT Table1.Primary_Key, Company_Name, Part_Number, Product_Desc, Innovate_Description, ' + @ColumnName + '
    FROM Table1 AS P
    LEFT JOIN Table2 AS A ON P.Primary_Key = A.Primary_Key
    PIVOT(MAX(A.VALUE) 
          FOR A.NAME IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'

--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
EXECUTE sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery

;
```

> And this is the Result for the Query that I keep getting: Msg 8156,
>   Level 16, State 1, Line 5 The column 'Primary_Key' was specified
>   multiple times for 'PVTTable'. Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The
>   multi-part identifier "Table1.Primary_Key" could not be bound.

Can anyone help me pivot these columns without the error message?  I only specified the Primary_Key in the code once so I do not know how I specified it multiple times and how it is unbound.

Comment: First change Table1.PrimaryKey to P.PrimaryKey.  Next, print out what's in @ColumnName and show it to us.

Answer (score 0):

you have a couple of things going on with your PIVOT statement that are problematic.  First you are attempting to reference table aliases for Table1 and Table2 but those aliases are not available in the final select of a PIVOT the Pivot command is kind of like an outer select and the only table alias that is then available is the pivot alias.

Next pivot's documenation states *"You can use the PIVOT and UNPIVOT relational operators to change a table-valued expression into another table"* (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx). Basically that means that you need a single table expression of only the uniquely named columns you want to be involved pivot being passed to the PIVOT command. The later part is likely the issue as Table1 and Table2 probably both have a column `Primary_Key` so pivot doesn't understand the reference.

To fix you can either move your Table1 & 2. join to an inner select and alias the table or build a cte and use the cte in your command.  Here is the former way:

```
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
  N'SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT Table1.Primary_Key, Company_Name, Part_Number, Product_Desc, Innovate_Description, ' + @ColumnName + '
    FROM Table1 AS P
    LEFT JOIN Table2 AS A ON P.Primary_Key = A.Primary_Key
) t
    PIVOT(MAX(A.VALUE) 
          FOR NAME IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'
```

Comment: Matt, it seems like the query you suggested works, but I am running into an issue because all of the new column headers that are pivoting from the Attribute_Name column are not recognized (since they do not exist) in Table1, so I keep getting errors for those values since they are not in that table.  Is there a way for me to pull those values from the join to enable it to run the query?

Comment: Can you update your post with the actual error?  If values are missing/note represented in your inner query it should just make that a column a NULL in your pivot.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below script..

```
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
  N'SELECT P.Primary_Key, Company_Name, Part_Number, Product_Desc, Innovate_Description, ' + @ColumnName + '
    FROM Table1 AS P
    LEFT JOIN Table2 AS A ON P.Primary_Key = A.Primary_Key
    PIVOT(MAX(A.VALUE) 
          FOR A.NAME IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'

--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
EXECUTE sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

Answer (score 0):

Those Name values get hardcoded to calculate that @ColumnName variable.

If the values are hardcoded anyway, then you might as well run the pivot with a join without building a SQL statement to execute.

```
SELECT A.Company_Name, A.Part_Number, A.Product_Desc, A.Innovate_Description, P.*
FROM (select Primary_Key, Name, Value from Innovate.dbo.Table1) T1
PIVOT(MAX(VALUE) FOR NAME IN (
  [Suture_-_2nd_Needle_Code],
  [Suture_-_Absorbable],
  [Suture_-_Antibacterial],
  [Suture_-_Armed],
  [Suture_-_Barbed],
  [Suture_-_Brand_Name],
  [Suture_-_C/R_2nd_Needle_Code],
  [Suture_-_C/R_Brand_Name],
  [Suture_-_C/R_length],
  [Suture_-_C/R_Needle_Code],
  [Suture_-_Coating],
  [Suture_-_Dyed],
  [Suture_-_Filament],
  [Suture_-_length_inches],
  [Suture_-_Looped],
  [Suture_-_Material],
  [Suture_-_Needle_Code],
  [Suture_-_Needle_Shape],
  [Suture_-_Needle_Style],
  [Suture_-_Noun],
  [Suture_-_pleget],
  [Suture_-_Popoff],
  [Suture_-_Suture_count],
  [Suture_-_Suture_size]
  )
) P
LEFT JOIN Innovate.dbo.Table2 AS A ON (A.Primary_Key = P.Primary_Key);
```

Fair enough, this has a disadvantage that if that [Primary_Key] needs to be the first column, that the `P.*` should be replaced by those literal column values. Or use the EXEC approach after all.

Anyway, to build name list for that @ColumnName variable, it can be done without all the OR's :

```
DECLARE @ColumnName NVARCHAR(MAX);
--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column 
SELECT @ColumnName = ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') + QUOTENAME(NAME)
FROM Innovate.dbo.Table1 
WHERE Name Like 'Suture_-_%'
AND SUBSTRING(Name,10,30) IN (
'2nd_Needle_Code',
'Absorbable',
'Antibacterial',
'Armed',
'Barbed',
'Brand_Name',
'C/R_2nd_Needle_Code',
'C/R_Brand_Name',
'C/R_length',
'C/R_Needle_Code',
'Coating',
'Dyed',
'Filament',
'length_inches',
'Looped',
'Material',
'Needle_Code',
'Needle_Shape',
'Needle_Style',
'Noun',
'pleget',
'Popoff',
'Suture_count',
'Suture_size')
GROUP BY Name;
```

Comment: The first code works great since I can interchange the hardcoded values, and would be specifying them myself anyways, as opposed to having sql go and fetch the values in a dynamic pivot.  Thanks!